# Most performant binding to this in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

recently, I've been using two ways to bind this in React.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      newData: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

versus

```
handleChange(e) => {
    ...
  }
```

but would need a `const this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`

Which would be more performant? Thanks.

Comment: The version without bind is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version without `bind` is most likely faster. `bind` has been known as a source of performance issues ever since ES5 came out because of all the edge cases `bind` is required to handle by the standard.

Benchmarking `bind` vs using closures shows that `bind` is most likely many times slower, as can be seen [here](https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-setup/32). And since arrow functions are just closures, in this case the arrow function will almost definitely be faster.